# How Regexp anchors \B and \b differs from each other?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.3

I just got a bit concept about `\B` and `\b` . And accordinlgy tried a code(taken from internet)but couldn't understand that - how the output has been generated by those `regexp Anchors`. So any one please help me to understand the difference between `\B` and `\b` by saying internally how they approach in `pattern matching` in Ruby?

```
Interactive ruby ready.
> str = "Hit him on the head\­n" +
      "Hit him on the head with a 2×4\n­"
=> "Hit him on the head
Hit him on the head with a 2??4
"
> str.scan(/­\w+\B/)
=> ["Hi", "hi", "o", "th", "hea", "Hi", "hi", "o", "th", "hea", "wit"]
> str.scan(/­\w+\b/)
=> ["Hit", "him", "on", "the", "head", "Hit", "him", "on", "the", "head", "with", "a", "2", "4"]
>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why in the above output of `str` came as `2??4` instead of `2x4`?

Answer (score 6):

Like most lower/upper case pairs, they are exact opposites:

`\b` matches a *word boundary* – that is, it matches *between* two letters (since it’s a zero-width match, i.e. it doesn’t consume a character when matching) where one belongs to a word and the other doesn’t. In the text “`this person`”, `\b` would match the following positions (denoted by a vertical bar): “`|this| |person|`”.

`\B` matches *anywhere but at a word boundary*. It would match at these positions: “`t|h|i|s p|e|r|s|o|n`” – that is, between all letters, but not between a letter and a non-letter character.

So if you have `\w+\b` and match “`this person`“ then you get as a result “`this`” because `+` is greedy and matches as many word characters (`\w`) as possible, up to the next word boundary.

`\w+\B` operates similarly, but it cannot match “`this`” since that is followed by a word boundary, which `\B` forbids. So the engine backtracks one character and matches “`thi`” instead.

Comment: I understod,but partially! Can it be visualized what you said in the post. Which might be helpful to have the concept in my mind quickly! Also a brief a idea with my exapmle `what are word boundaries` in my example senteces?

Comment: @DoLoveSky The best visualisation I can think of is actually the one in the second and third paragraph, where I’ve shown the potential match positions of the two expressions using vertical bars.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html @DoLoveSky, once you got a realively solid idea of how regex engines match expressions you'll understand more easily anything related to regex. I strongly recommend you to start there.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Just one more question here - why `2×4\n­` didn't come in the output `str.scan(/­\w+\B/)` of this?

Comment: @DoLoveSky I’m confused: why would it? First of all, the string contains no word boundary since there’s no word character, hence `\B` never matches (`\w`, however, does, since it matches letters *and numbers*; well, technically `\B` matches after `\n`). Secondly, even if it *did* match, your expression starts with a dash which occurs nowhere in the string.